# VS code async function and axios

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code is unable to recognise async function and places a squiggly line on the keyword function.

It throws me an parse error saying unexpected token function but the code compiles and runs fine.

```
async function authorizeMe(url,data,config) {
try {
  let res = await axios.default.post(
            url,
            data,
            config
            );

  return res;
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
};

authorizeMe(url,data,config)
.then(res => console.log(res.data.client_id))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

There is another issue axios.post does not show up in intellisense of VSCode but axios.default.post works.

How do i fix both the issues any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably not in Visual Studio Code, but more likely in the eslint configuration.

(At least) On linux, you can test eslint on the command line:

```
eslint myfile.js
```

This should produce the same error. You can view your currently set eslint configuration with:

```
eslint --print-config .
```

Check for files `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json` starting in your project directory or in its parent directories. In my case the problem seemed to be the "ecmaVersion": 6 parser option

```
"parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        ...
```

With `"ecmaVersion": 8`, eslint stopped complaining about the function kyword when used with async.